# How to calculate last business day of month in VBScript

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript

How do I calculate the last business day of month in VBScript? It is for a Reporting Services report.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
intMonth=11
'Use zero to return last day of previous month '
LastDayOfMonth= dateserial(2008,intMonth+1,0)

'Saturday '
If WeekDay(LastDayOfMonth,1)=7 Then LastDayOfMonth=LastDayOfMonth-1
'Sunday '
If WeekDay(LastDayOfMonth,1)=1 Then LastDayOfMonth=LastDayOfMonth-2

Msgbox LastDayOfMonth & "  " & Weekdayname(Weekday(LastDayOfMonth,1),1)
```

Comment: +1 for using "first day of next month" algorithm -- delegates the calendar details to library routines.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good CodeProject article here: [**Working With Business Dates (Business Holidays/Weekends, etc)**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/BusinessDates.aspx).

> This project is aimed at easing the
>   troubles of figuring out valid
>   business dates. It includes a few
>   functions I have created to determine
>   whether or not the date is a holiday
>   or a weekend, and also to retrieve
>   either the next or last business day.
>   There is also a function to find the
>   last day of a given month.

```
Function LastBusinessDay(sDate)

   Dim iDay, iDaysToAdd, iDate

   iDaysToAdd = 0
   iDate = sDate

   x = 1

   Do while iDaysToAdd >= 0

      If Weekday(iDate) = 1 or Weekday(iDate) = 7 or _
                isHoliday(iDate) <> 0 then
         iDay = Weekday(iDate)
         Select Case cint(iDay)
            Case 1  'Sunday

               iDate = DateAdd("d", -1, iDate)

            Case 7  'Saturday

               iDate = DateAdd("d", -1, iDate)

            Case else    'this is a valid day

                if isHoliday(iDate) > 0 then
                    iDate = dateadd("d", -(isHoliday(iDate)), iDate)
                else
                    iDaysToAdd = iDaysToAdd - 1
                end if

         End Select
      end if
   Loop

   LastBusinessDay = iDate
End Function
```

P.S.: You'll find the functions `LastDayOfMonth` and `isHoliday` in the article.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for anyone who is looking to get Last business day of the previous month.

```
Dim lastbusinessdayofprevmonth

Sub GetLastDay()

Dim curdate
curdate = Date()    

Dim firstdayofcurmonth 
firstdayofcurmonth = Month(curdate) & "/1/" & Year(curdate)

Dim lastdayofprevmonth
lastdayofprevmonth = DateAdd("d", -1, firstdayofcurmonth)

Dim day
day = weekday(lastdayofprevmonth)


if(day = 1) then
    lastbusinessdayofprevmonth = DateAdd("d", -2, lastdayofprevmonth)
elseif (day = 7) then
    lastbusinessdayofprevmonth = DateAdd("d", -1, lastdayofprevmonth)
else
    lastbusinessdayofprevmonth = lastdayofprevmonth
end if

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the last **week** day of the month (M-F), then try:

```
Dim d

d = DateAdd("m", 1, Now)

d = Month(d) & "/1/" & Year(d)
d = DateAdd("d", -1, d)

If Weekday(d) = 7 Then
    d = DateAdd("d", -1, d)
ElseIf Weekday(d) = 1 Then
    d = DateAdd("d", -2, d)
End If

MsgBox d
```