# How to get start and end of previous month in VB

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im trying to create some VB code that will get the start and end of the previous month.
Im able to the current month which is just:

```
Month(DateValue(Now))
```

which would return 3. From there I can take away 1 to give me 2 meaning February. This is fine but what about when I Im in January and I repeat this and it gives me zero - my code will fail. Any one know how to get the previous months start and end day then?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The first day of the previous month is always 1, to get the last day of the previous month, use 0 with DateSerial:

```
''Today is 20/03/2013 in dd/mm/yyyy
DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),0) = 28/02/2013 
DateSerial(Year(Date),1,0) = 31/12/2012
```

You can get the first day from the above like so:

```
LastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),0)
FirstDay = LastDay-Day(LastDay)+1
```

See also: [How to caculate last business day of month in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302597/how-to-caculate-last-business-day-of-month-in-vbscript/302652#302652)

Comment: Hi Remou was just going over your code again and have another question - why is it that when i do this: LastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1 - 1) i get 31/01/2013 instead of 28/02/2013? Surely the Month(Date) - 1 returns 2 implying February

Comment: You have month -2, once for month(date)-1, once for 0 for day. The zeroth day of this month is the last day of the previous month, so February is dateserial(2013,3,0), not as you show.

Comment: ohh ok - thats decieving. Thanks

Comment: ?DateSerial(Year(12/1/2015),Month(12/31/2015),0) 
11/30/1899 <--- this is what I get when I run this in VB immediate window. How can I make it so it shows 2015 instead of 1899

Comment: @barry17 You are passing `12/1/2015` which gets interpreted as math and evaluates to somethings like this: `DateSerial(Year(0.00595533498759305210918114143921),Month(0.00019210758024493716581229488513568),0)` Enclose the dates in quotes like this: `DateSerial(Year("12/1/2015"),Month("12/31/2015"),0) `. Excel won't implicitly convert ints to dates but it will convert strings to dates.

Answer (score 7):

I have similar formula for the First and Last Day

The First Day of the month

```
FirstDay = DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),1)
```

The zero Day of the next month is the Last Day of the month

```
LastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date)+ 1,0)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
firstDay = DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1)
lastDay = DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1))
```

This is another way to do it, but I think Remou's version looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
First_Day_Of_Previous_Month = New Date(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1)

Last_Day_Of_Previous_Month = New Date(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: This is not VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This works reliably for me in my main sub.

```
Dim defDate1 As Date, defDate2 As Date

'** Set default date range to previous month
defDate1 = CDate(Month(Now) & "/1/" & Year(Now))
defDate1 = DateAdd("m", -1, defDate1)
defDate2 = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, defDate1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the month in number form:

```
Month(DateAdd("m", -3, Now))
```

It will give you `12` for December.

So in your case you would use `Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now))` to just subract one month.

Comment: How does that get both start and end _day_ of previous month?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to what @Fionnuala Said, The below functions can be used. These even work for leap years.

```
'If you pass #2016/20/01# you get #2016/31/01#
Public Function GetLastDate(tempDate As Date) As Date
    GetLastDate = DateSerial(Year(tempDate), Month(tempDate) + 1, 0)
End Function

'If you pass #2016/20/01# you get 31
Public Function GetLastDay(tempDate As Date) As Integer
    GetLastDay = Day(DateSerial(Year(tempDate), Month(tempDate) + 1, 0))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function GetFOMPrev(ByVal tdate As Date) As Date
    Return tdate.AddDays(-(tdate.Day - 1))
End Function

Public Shared Function GetEOMPrev(ByVal tdate As Date) As Date
    Return tdate.AddDays(-tdate.Day)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
'Get End of Month of Previous Month - Pass today's date
EOM = GetEOMPrev(Date.Today)

'Get First of Month of Previous Month - Pass date just calculated
FOM = GetFOMPrev(EOM)
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not VBA.

Comment: Why not adding an explanation to your code to improve the post?

Comment: I haven't used VBA in several years - can someone tell me if this is a better solution to the accepted answer? Though I expect an upvote would answer my own question...